# How do I limit the width of an anchor HTML element (<a> tag)?

Tags: css, html

I am trying to limit the width of an A html element which so it would be snortened and avoid taking too much space on screen.

At this moment I do not have the flexibility of changing the structure of the document so I am looking for a pure CSS solution.

I tried this but it didn't had any effect, the text still takes all the space available.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            a.data {
                color: red;
                text-overflow: ellipsis;
                width: 4ch;
                max-width: 4ch;
                overflow: hidden;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <span>
            <a class="data">012345668</a>
            and some other text
        </span>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 5):

Changing the `a`'s display property to `inline-block` will do the trick:

```css
a.data {
  color: red;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  width: 4ch;
  max-width: 4ch;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<span><a class="data">012345668</a> and some other text</span>
```

The reason is that the default display for `a` is `inline`. `inline` elements don't accept `width`, `max-width`, `min-width` and the same for `height`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```css
 a.data {
            color: red;
            text-overflow: ellipsis;
            max-width: 4ch;
            display:inline-block;
            overflow:hidden;
            vertical-align:top;
        }
```

```html
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <span style="display:inline-block">
        <a class="data">012345668</a> and some other text
    </span>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You have a unterminated span :)

Comment: I fixed it. Thanks @Simon Hayter